Recieved "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types..." when input is a NumPy array
I am attempting to adapt code from this recently published paper for my own datasets. The .ipnyb file is available here. My data is formatted using the same pre-processing workflow (in R) described by the authors. It's my first time working in Python, so I apologise in advance for any confusing language or seemingly obvious mistakes.
Issues first started with reading in the particular reference taxa dataset I need, which is fish rather than mammals, and dropping the required columns/rows to create the necessary "reference" and "ref_peaks" dataframes.  I found a workaround by reading in two separate .csv files-- one for reference peaks with only peak values, the other with only the taxa information. I then combined them so I have the same type of reference dataframe that is required later in the function, with columns including Order, Family, Common Name, Species and all the relevant peptide positions, and all rows showing the correct data (characters for the first 4 columns, followed by numerical values or NaN for the peptide position columns).
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Archaeology 2024/Thesis Re-runs/PP_Combo_1/Combo_1_C66.csv", sep=',')
ref_taxa = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Archaeology 2024/Thesis Re-runs/Taxa.csv', sep=",", encoding='UTF-8', header=None, names=fields)
ref_peaks = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Archaeology 2024/Thesis Re-runs/Edited_ZooMS_Values.csv', sep=",", encoding='UTF-8', header=None, names=fields2)
ref_taxa = ref_taxa.iloc[1:]
ref_peaks = ref_peaks.iloc[1:]
references = pd.concat([ref_taxa,ref_peaks], axis=1)

So the function I want to run is as follows:
def transform(df):
    df_copy = df.copy() # making a copy so I dont have to reload the dataframe everytime
    #then changes are made to df_copy   
    x = np.arange(500, 3500, 0.1)
    pi = np.array(ref_peaks.iloc[0].to_numpy())
    pi = pi[~np.isnan(pi)]      
    resampled = np.zeros_like(x)
    for p in df_copy['mass']:
        resampled[np.logical_and(p-x>-0.3,p-x<1.3)] = 1
        
    resampled_smooth = gaussian_filter1d(resampled, 100)
    plt.plot(x, resampled, label='sample', linewidth=1)
    plt.plot(x, resampled_smooth, label='sample', linewidth=1)
    
    n_spec = ref_peaks.shape[0]
    corrs = np.zeros(n_spec)
    for i in range(n_spec):
        y = np.zeros_like(x)
        pi = np.array(ref_peaks.iloc[i].to_numpy())
        pi = pi[~np.isnan(pi)]
        for p in pi:
            y[np.logical_and(p-x>-0.3,p-x<1.3)] = 1
            corrs[i] = np.corrcoef(y, resampled)[0,1]
        ranks = pd.DataFrame({'Order':reference['Order'][1:],'Family':reference['Family'][1:], 'Species':reference['Species'][1:], 'ZooMS_taxon':reference['ZooMS_taxon'][1:], 'Correlation':corrs})
    
    idx = ranks.sort_values(by='Correlation', ascending=False).index[:6] - 1
    # index [6] because the first 6 matches of species will be determined -- number depends on how many of the first n most likely species you want to look at
    
    all_d = pd.DataFrame(columns=ref_peaks.columns)
    for i in idx:
        y = np.zeros_like(x)
        pi = np.array(ref_peaks.iloc[i].to_numpy())
        pi = pi[~np.isnan(pi)]
        for p in pi:
            y[np.logical_and(p-x>-0.3,p-x<1.3)] = 1
        
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x, y * resampled)
        plt.title(reference['Species'][i+1]);

        v, ix, iy = np.intersect1d((np.round(pi, decimals=1)*10).astype(int), (x[y*resampled==1]*10).astype(int), return_indices=True)
 
        d = pd.DataFrame({k:p for k, p in zip(ref_peaks.columns[ix],v/10)}, 
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(reference['Species'][i+1], reference['Family'][i+1], reference['Order'][i+1], reference['ZooMS_taxon'][i+1])],
                                                 names=['Species', 'Family', 'Order', 'ZooMS_taxon'])).reset_index()

        all_d = pd.concat([all_d, d], axis=0)
    
    ranks_df = ranks.sort_values(by='Correlation', ascending=False)

    
    return all_d

However, when you execute transform(df), this error is returned:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-1fbc44e09cc7> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 transform(df)

<ipython-input-26-775d7a15bb53> in transform(df)
      7     print(type(pi))
      8     print(type(pi[1]))
----> 9     pi = pi[~np.isnan(pi)]
     10     resampled = np.zeros_like(x)
     11     for p in df_copy['mass']:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

I checked the type of both "pi" and the first line, and "pi" is returned as <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, which is what it should be, but
print(type(pi[0]))

returns <class 'float'>, which is, I think, what is causing the error when the line
pi = pi[~np.isnan(pi)]

is being run (this may be wrong though, I might be misunderstanding what type of data np.isnan requires/works with).
So my questions are then why is the data within the 'pi' array not being read as numbers and NaN values? Why has it been classed as float? Am I missing something ridiculously obvious about what is causing this error?

What is pi.dtype?

ref_peaks.iloc[i].to_numpy() is a array.  Don't need the extra np.array. What is ref_peaks.dtypes

Sorry, first reply I posted was incorrect. The command ref_peaks.dtypes says it's dtype is "object"-- is this where the issue lies?

Columns of a dataframe often are object dtype.  For example if they contain one or more strings.  So that ends up affecting the array made from the frame.  np.isnan only works for numeric dtype arrays, since it is checking for float values (inf and nan).  I believe pandas has a more flexible 'nan' test.  Also converting to a numeric column may be easier at the dataframe level.
